# Valid Values for Terraform Postgres aws_db_instance enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports Argument

Tags: postgresql, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The Terraform `aws_db_instance` resource has the `enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports` argument which lists valid values with a note that the actual allowed values are dependent on database engine (see [this link](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/db_instance.html#enabled_cloudwatch_logs_exports)).  However, the documentation does not say which values are valid for which database engines.  Specifically I am interested in the valid values for postgres.  Does anyone know where I can find a list of such valid values?

Answer (score 1):

This feature only [recently became available for PostgreSQL](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/amazon-rds-supports-postgresql-logfiles-publish-to-amazon-cloudwatch-logs/).  I submitted a [PR6829](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/pull/6829) to the AWS provider to add the two values that PostgreSQL >9.6.6 support ('postgresql' and 'upgrade').